# JavaScript TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting this a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when testing my aws lambda. The code is

```
'use strict';

const snsPublisher = require('./snsPublisher');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    console.log('From SNS:', message);
    callback(null, message);
};

module.exports.snsLamdbaTriggered = (event, context, callback) => {
  var topic = event.Records[0].Sns.TopicArn;
  var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
  console.log(topic + '  ' + message);
  callback(null, { message: 'SNS lamdba was triggered from the topic ' + topic + ' with message ' + message , event });
};
```

When I change the value inside the brackets I still continue to get the same error. Does anyone know where the problem may lie?

Comment: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" says, that `event.Records` is `undefined` ...

Comment: Clearly `event.Records` is undefined. Is there a reason to expect that `event` should always have a `Records` key?

Comment: can you add a log on event object and check Records property?

Answer (score 0):

When invoking a lambda function using SNS, the function expects an *event object* that has specific attributes. So, "testing" your lambda function would fail unless you configure your lambda test event to look exactly the same as an [SNS event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sns), for example:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": eventsubscriptionarn,
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "Sns": {
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "Message": "Hello from SNS!",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        },
        "Type": "Notification",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "TopicArn": topicarn,
        "Subject": "TestInvoke"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```